# probleme with putting data in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

hello im having trouble putting data in listview 
i created the resource file for it and i made the custom array adapter for it but when i run the app it shuts down

here is the custom adapter class

```
public class MembreAdapter  extends BaseAdapter{
private Context context;
private List<Membre> memb;

public MembreAdapter(Context context, List<Membre> memb) {
    this.context = context;
    this.memb = memb;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return memb.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return memb.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v= View.inflate(context,R.layout.display_member_row,null);
    TextView tnom = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.nom_id);
    TextView tprenom = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.prenom_id);
    TextView temail = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.email_id);
    TextView tnumero= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.numero_tele_id);

    tnom.setText(memb.get(position).getNom());
    tprenom.setText(memb.get(position).getPrenom());
    temail.setText(memb.get(position).getEmail());
    tnumero.setText(memb.get(position).getNumero());// thats the line that sstack trace points at 
    return v;
    }
}
```

and the class that i want to show the data in

```
 BaseDeDonee bdd = new BaseDeDonee(this);//database
    mem=new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor c =bdd.GETallMem();
    //function returns all the data from table person
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(c.moveToNext()){
        nom= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nom"));
        prenom=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("prenom"));
        email=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("profile"));
        numero=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("numero_tel"));

        mem.add(new Membre(nom,prenom,email,numero));
    }

    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

   mema= new MembreAdapter(getApplicationContext(),mem);
    listView.setAdapter(mema);
    listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"it works " ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

[image: Stack trace]

thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are giving an integer to the setText method which makes it try to find an string resource with an id equal to that integer , that causes a resource not found exception.

try changing it to

```
tnumero.setText(""+memb.get(position).getNumero());
```

Comment: it works thank so much man i honestly dont know what to say but thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a String to the setText method. Try this -

```
tnumero.setText(Integer.toString(memb.get(position).getNumero()));
```